# Quadratic Formula NaN

Tags: java

I am trying to find the Quadratic Formula for this program and I'm not sure which mistake I have made, but it seems that it isn't working for me. The output comes out as "NaN" for the inputs (5, -8, 3), (3, 2, -7). Keep in mind I have another class to test these methods, and I can post if necessary.

EDITED CODE:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import static java.lang.System.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class Quadratic
{
    private int a, b, c;
    private double rootOne;
    private double rootTwo;

    public Quadratic()
    {

    }

    public Quadratic(int quadA, int quadB, int quadC)
    {
        a = quadA;
        b = quadB;
        c = quadC;
    }

    public void setEquation(int quadA, int quadB, int quadC)
    {
        a = quadA;
        b = quadB;
        c = quadC;
    }

    public void calcRoots( )
    {
        rootOne = (-b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b,2)-4*a*c))/(2*a);
        rootTwo = (-b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b,2)-4*a*c))/(2*a);
    }

    public void print( )
    {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("ROOTS :: "+ rootOne);
        System.out.println("\t" + rootTwo);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

TEST CLASS:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import static java.lang.System.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class QuadraticRunner
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
   {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(in);

        System.out.print("ENTER A :: ");
        int a = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("ENTER B :: ");
        int b = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("ENTER C :: ");
        int c = keyboard.nextInt();

        Quadratic test = new Quadratic();
        test.calcRoots();
        test.print();


        System.out.print("ENTER A :: ");
        a = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("ENTER B :: ");
        b = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("ENTER C :: ");
        c = keyboard.nextInt();

        test.calcRoots();
        test.print();


        System.out.print("ENTER A :: ");
        a = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("ENTER B :: ");
        b = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("ENTER C :: ");
        c = keyboard.nextInt();

        test.calcRoots();
        test.print();
   }
}
```

Comment: Please show us how you are initializating and using this class' methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test you never actually set `a`, `b` and `c`. You use the no-argument Quadratic constructor:

```
Quadratic test = new Quadratic();
```

And you don't call `setEquation`.

The default value of `a`, `b` and `c` is 0 so this is why you are getting NaN ("Not a Number") values:

```
( -0 + Math.sqrt( Math.pow( 0 , 2 ) - 4 * 0 * 0 ) ) / ( 2 * 0 )
    ==
( 0.0 ) / ( 0.0 ) // IEEE division of zero by zero results in NaN
```

Use the `(int, int, int)` constructor or `setEquation`.

```
Quadratic test = new Quadratic(a, b, c);
test.setEquation(a, b, c);
```

Comment: FYI: in the IEEE standard, divide by zero results in `NaN` only if you divide 0/0; anything else/0 will result in plus or minus infinity.

Comment: @ajb Yes you're correct. 0.0/0.0 is what they are getting.

Comment: @ajb `NaN/0` is also NaN.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing parentheses.

```
rootOne = (-b + Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
```

Additionally you have not dealt with any of the special cases like imaginary roots, repeated root, etc.

Comment: Also: `float getVertexX(){return -b/2f*a;};` :)

Comment: I am doing this for a comp sci class and I think they just want the simplest form of the quadratic formula [link to assignment](https://www.schoology.com/docviewer/258646862/a61f78b475c24c772c8303bebcff9ba6). I also added the edit you suggested but it still has "NaN", maybe "b" somehow is negative? Thanks for the help <3

Comment: @Certus Well I said you didn't deal with special cases.  When a=0, the quadratic formula fails.  The quadratic degenerates to bx+c = 0, so you solve for x, x=-c/b.  This is the linear case. Never write software without understanding the math.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Java also returns `NaN` or `Infinity` when a floating-point division has zero for the denominator.  See the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2).  Make sure you check for these things.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use the `setEquation()` method and instance variables. I think that could get you into unnecessary trouble.

You can do it like this without having to store instance variables:

```
public double [] calcRoots(int a, int b, int c)
{
    double[] roots = new double[2];

    roots[0] = (-b + Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
    roots[1] = (-b - Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);

    return roots;
}
```

Comment: You forgot: `float x2=b*b-4*a*c;` , `boolean isReal=x2>=0;` , `float sqrt=Math.sqrt(isReal?x2:x2*-1)` , `float root1=-b+sqrt/2*a, root2=-b-sqrt/2*a`

Comment: Thank you for the help but like I mentioned @Gene, this is for a beginner Comp Sci course so I haven't learned that yet and so my teacher would know that it isn't my work and I also haven't gotten that far yet D: Is there any way to use the method similarly to how I have in my code shown?

Comment: @Certus I don't know what to say to that. I find it somewhat sad; almost like you are stopping yourself from learning. PS that is only an array. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: I just don't want to put something into my code that I don't understand. I'm sure it would be fine if I put it in, as long as I can explain what I did. One question I do have: what error is causing me to use different code? By the way, thank you for the link. I'll make sure to check it out and learn more about this : )

Comment: Use `double`, not `float`.  `double` gives you more precision and there is hardly any reason to use `float`.

Comment: @ajb: If that is directed at me, I was using `float` as an abstract concept of a floating-point number (fpn) to distinguish the use between an integer and a fpn. OP should not be using integers when dividing, especially with polynomial math.